# Related Item link goes missing

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

In the collaboration library I added a Related Item to a document. However, when the documents are moved to a Records Center the Related Item link is removed.

I tried another test by moving the document that has a Related Item attached using a move tool (Third Party tool) to another folder within the same library and the Related Item attachment gets lost.

Is the "Related Item" column that starts as a hidden field only unhidden for documents that will not be moved at all?  What about all the documents that will be moved to a Records Center which is in a different Web App?  I am working in SharePoint 2013 and the Related Item link goes missing if the document gets moved.  Is this the way it works for others or am I missing something?  Thanks